# How to find which node name is invalid in Slurm error: "sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Invalid node name specified"

Tags: linux, slurm

I'm getting this error "sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Invalid node name specified" for this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --gpus=1
#SBATCH -p overcap
#SBATCH -A overcap
#SBATCH --signal=USR1@120
#SBATCH --time=10:00
#SBATCH --requeue
#SBATCH --nodelist=brainiac,omgwth,cyborg,sonny,robby,spd-13,qt-1,dave,nestor,crushinator,deebot,xaea-12,baymax,megabot,randotron,chappie,heistotron,roberto,herbie,shakey,chitti,samantha,clippy,kitt,tachikoma
#SBATCH -o err_test.out

srun python src/train.py
```

is there a way to find out which node is invalid in the list?

Comment: Sure - exclude one by one until found

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sinfo` or `sinfo -N` to get the list of valid node names for your slurm configuration.  Then compare with what's in your script.